# Is there a better way to create a file in bash other than using touch and echo?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, echo

I created a bash script that installed some applications and wrote a .conf file. I wanted my bash script to create the file for me so I could just run the file and it set it all up. was there a better way of going about it than this or did I do it in the best way possible. just wondering what other options I had.

Note: the file does work

```
if [ ! -e ~/.conf/file/path ]; then
   touch ~/.conf/file/path
   echo "
    long
    conf
    list
    here
    ..." >> ~/.conf/file/path
fi
```

Comment: See [Create , Write and Save file from a Shell script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447150/create-write-and-save-file-from-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your script goes, you can use `>` redirection to file. You're asking if the file doesn't exist (which should better be expressed as `if ! [ -e ~/.conf/file/path ];`), therefore there is no need to use `append` operator in this particular case (even though it works alright).

As for printing long multiline configuration into the file, Panther already hinted at use of [here docs](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286) in his [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966127/is-there-a-better-way-to-create-a-file-in-bash-other-than-using-touch-and-echo#comment1546986_966131) under [Thomas's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966131/295286).  This is a frequent technique I personally use for writing "help message" or options information in my scripts

You could easily do something like this:

```
bash-4.3$ cat <<EOF > out.txt
parameter1="value 1"
parameter2="value 2"
EOF
bash-4.3$ cat out.txt
parameter1="value 1"
parameter2="value 2"
bash-4.3$
```

Or alternatively create a specific function, `write_config()` to make your script more idiomatic, so to speak:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# note usage of $HOME variable instead of ~
my_config="$HOME/my_conf_file.txt"
# declare all functions at the top
config_exists()[[ -e "$my_config" ]]

write_config(){
    cat > "$my_config" <<EOF
parameter1="value 1"
parameter2="varlue 2"
EOF
}

if ! config_exists;
then
    echo "config doesn't exist"
    write_config
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

Just do `echo "text" >> /path/to/file` if the file doesn't exist.

The lovely thing about text redirection and appending is that if your output is a file path, and the file doesn't already exist, it'll create the file, regardless of if `>` or `>>` is used.  No need to `touch` the file at all, typically.  (Though, if you are sure the file does not exist, just use `>` instead of `>>`; `>>` is to append to a file, but if the file doesn't exist, well...)

Comment: Ok thanks for your input. I will keep that in mind

Comment: Better, IMO, use a HERE Document - https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_documents

Answer (score 0):

If the "long conf list" is so long that it impedes the readability of your shell script, why not just place it into a separate file that accompanies the script?  Then all your need to do in the shell script is copy that file to the destination.

```
if [ ! -e ~/.conf/file/path ]; then
   cp /path/to/mytemplate ~/.conf/file/path
fi
```